# how to set empty space when records is not into data base

Tags: php, mysql

i am created html form ,when i click on submit button i get records from data base,but if the data is not in to the data base its print

```
    http://bukkyolu.com/mp3/upload/
```

that not come form database its just static value that i am print in statement bellow

```
    http://bukkyolu.com/mp3/upload/".$row['2']."'> ,
    if the .$row['2'].is not in to database
```

i want empty space not default link that printed

```
<?php
$category=$_POST["category"];
$month=$_POST["month"];

$mysql_hostname = "localhost";
$mysql_user = "root";
$mysql_password = "";
$mysql_database = "bukkyolu_mp3";
$bd = mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password)
or die("Opps some thing went wrong");
mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $bd) or die("Opps some thing went wrong");

    $query  = "SELECT title,Amp3,Bmp3,Cmp3 FROM mp3_data WHERE`category` = '$category' and `month` = '$month' ";
$result1 = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result1);
//echo $row['s_id'];

 echo "<table border='1' align='center' >";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result1)){
 // echo "<td><a href='#' onclick='someFunction()'>" .$row['0']. "</a> </td>";
   echo "<tr><th>Title:</th><td>".$row['0']."</td></tr>";  
 echo "<tr><th>African:</th><td><a href 'http://bukkyolu.com/mp3/upload/".$row['1']."'>http://bukkyolu.com/mp3/upload/".$row['0']."</a></td></tr>";
 echo "<tr><th>British:</th><td><a href 'http://bukkyolu.com/mp3/upload/".$row['2']."'>http://bukkyolu.com/mp3/upload/".$row['0']."</a></td></tr>";
 echo "<tr><th>Caribbean:</th><td><a href 'http://bukkyolu.com/mp3/upload/".$row['3']."'>http://bukkyolu.com/mp3/upload/".$row['3']."</a></td></tr>";
  echo "<tr></tr>";
  echo "<tr></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

?>
```

Comment: Check before every value whether it is empty or not before appending if it's empty put and else condition in that put a blank space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for the value as below.

```
if(isset($row['0']) && $row['0'] != "")
{
   echo "<tr><th>African:</th><td><a href 'http://bukkyolu.com/mp3/upload/".$row['1']."'>http://bukkyolu.com/mp3/upload/".$row['0']."</a></td></tr>";
}
else
{
   echo "<tr><th>African:</th><td>...</td></tr>";
}
```

Do the same for other.

**OR**

Create function that will more like a good programming habit.

```
function checkForValue($value)
{
    $response = "&nbsp";// you can also add ... or anything 
    if(isset($value) && $value != "")
    {
        $response = $value;
    }
    return $response;
}
```

and call it as .

```
echo "<tr><th>Title:</th><td>".checkForValue($row['0'])."</td></tr>";
```

Comment: dipesh but i am getting http://bukkyolu.com/mp3/upload/ link that i set default,i dont want  alos this if $row['3'],not in to the data base

Comment: @NikunjJagad see my updated answer in first option i have added code

Comment: can you give me your email id pls if you dont have any problem

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 isset($row['0'])?$row['0']:''

 while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result1)){
   // echo "<td><a href='#' onclick='someFunction()'>" .$row['0']. "</a> </td>";
   echo "<tr><th>Title:</th><td>".isset($row['0'])?$row['0']."</td></tr>";  
   echo "<tr><th>African:</th><td><a href 'http://bukkyolu.com/mp3/upload/".isset($row['1'])?$row['1']:''."'>http://bukkyolu.com/mp3/upload/".isset($row['0'])?$row['0']:''."</a></td></tr>";
   echo "<tr><th>British:</th><td><a href 'http://bukkyolu.com/mp3/upload/".isset($row['2'])?$row['2']:''."'>http://bukkyolu.com/mp3/upload/".$row['0']."</a></td></tr>";
   echo "<tr><th>Caribbean:</th><td><a href 'http://bukkyolu.com/mp3/upload/".isset($row['3'])?$row['3']:''."'>http://bukkyolu.com/mp3/upload/".isset($row['3'])$row['3']:''."</a></td></tr>";
   echo "<tr></tr>";
   echo "<tr></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

etc in this way you can set space if value does not exits

hope it will help!

Comment: you also need to check if value is blank or not...because i think $row[0] will always present..

Comment: @DipeshParmar well in that case even that will not be necessary as  while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result1)){} this fetch data if record exits then only it will enter in to the loop

Comment: you did not get what i am trying to say...i know loop will perform only for record found but record row can be empty...get it.?

Comment: @DipeshParmar yes and that's why the empty or isset($row['0'])?$row['0']:'' will do the trick , currect me if I am wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Add additional condition that if your query has no results found.
It will just do else with no `mysql_fetch_rows` because `mysql_fetch_rows` needed outputs to be fetch..

```
if(count($result1) > 0){
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result1)){
     // echo "<td><a href='#' onclick='someFunction()'>" .$row['0']. "</a> </td>";
       echo "<tr><th>Title:</th><td>".(!empty($row['0'])? $row['0']: ' '."</td></tr>";  


     echo "<tr><th>African:</th><td><a href '".(!empty($row['0']))? 'http://bukkyolu.com/mp3/upload/'.$row['0'] : ' '."'>".(!empty($row['0']))? 'http://bukkyolu.com/mp3/upload/'.$row['0'] : ' '."</a></td></tr>";

     echo "<tr><th>African:</th><td><a href '".(!empty($row['0']))? 'http://bukkyolu.com/mp3/upload/'.$row['2'] : ' '."'>".(!empty($row['0']))? 'http://bukkyolu.com/mp3/upload/'.$row['0'] : ' '."</a></td></tr>";
     echo "<tr><th>British:</th><td><a href '".(!empty($row['0']))? 'http://bukkyolu.com/mp3/upload/'.$row['3'] : ' '."'>".(!empty($row['0']))? 'http://bukkyolu.com/mp3/upload/'.$row['3'] : ' '."</a></td></tr>";
      echo "<tr></tr>";
      echo "<tr></tr>";
    }
}
else{
     echo "<tr><th>Title:</th><td> </td></tr>";  
     echo "<tr><th>African:</th><td><a href 'javascript:void(0);'> </a></td></tr>";
     echo "<tr><th>African:</th><td><a href 'javascript:void(0);'> </a></td></tr>";
     echo "<tr><th>British:</th><td><a href 'javascript:void(0);'> </a></td></tr>";
      echo "<tr></tr>";
      echo "<tr></tr>";
}
```

try to include ternary condition in each of your result

so that if the fetch data is empty it will display the other condition as `' '`

Comment: kaii i am trying your code i am getting error like :mysql_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in

Comment: added additional condition that if results are zero another condition will executed that no need of mysql_fetch_row